# "line of work they are in "

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I thought this was absolutely brilliant on the Salvation Army’s part! People are more willing to support the men and women who protect us, no matter **what line of work they are in**. And who doesn’t like hearing bagpipes play on Christmas – there’s just something very **Christmas-like about them**. While not exactly an ad, this probably helped bring in more donations for the Salvation Army.

what do "line of work they are in" and "brilliant on" mean here?
and
Is ad stand for "advertisement"?

Comment: Did you do any researches before asking this question?

Comment: If you search the Oxford dictionary for "line of work" [the definition for line](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/line#line__46) has a good explanation.

Comment: @MARamezani yes i searched, but its meaning doesn't make sense in given text.

Comment: Why not? "Branch of activity"....

Comment: This meaning for the expression is even better at [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/line+of+work).

Comment: @MARamezani can I ask another question about this text?

Comment: Of course, and I accidentally down-voted your post. Edit it so that I could retrieve the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "[line of work](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/line+of+work)" is a person's job or career field.

The sentence is a little awkward, but from the given text it seems to mean:

> "No matter what type of job a person has, they are willing to support
>   men & women who protect us"

The Salvation Army is a U.S. charitable organization that does most of its fund-raising around the winter holidays. Salvation Army funds typically go to help poor children/families, so without more context it's unusual that the support would go explicitly to people "who protect us."

Bagpipes make me think it refers to police (they're often seen marching/playing in parades). Was this in relation to NYPD shootings or something? Raising funds for policemen shot on duty?

Salvation Army volunteers are known for ringing bells outside stores, and standing next to red buckets where people can make donations. Perhaps instead of ringing a bell & collecting for kids they had a police bagpiper collecting for specific NYPD families instead?